# Small SSD, large SATA. What can I move to SATA?

Tags: partitioning, mount, ssd, sata, io

I've got a 601GB Linux partition which can be written to at up to 84.7MB/s ([ref](http://hdd.userbenchmark.com/SpeedTest/784/TOSHIBA-MQ01ABD100)). My 62GB can be written to at 366MB/s ([ref](http://ssd.userbenchmark.com/Samsung-840-Evo-120GB/Rating/1886)).

Down to my last ~360MB. What should I move over and mount from my other drive?

Comment: Should be concerned about the SSD wearing out prematurely from too many writes, I'd avoid putting swap there, & `/tmp` & `/var` too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving `/opt` and my `Projects` directory to other partitions solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

The most common directories to move from an SSD and mount to a HDD are:

`/home` `/var` `/tmp` `/usr` `swap`

Comment: I don't know why everyone always wants to move swap off the SSD.  Just set swappiness to 10 and keep it on the SSD.  That way, the system will be much more responsive when swapping...  You just need a good quality SLC SSD.

Comment: @Fabby op is looking for space not speed.

Comment: who uses swap anymore?

Answer (score 1):

You should install your OS on the SSD. The /home partition will be on the slower hdd.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the ssd as a cache drive in the raid utility with conjunction with your hdd. In that way your mobo (if supported) can automatically detect and cache in the ssd your most used data without you setting mount points and it works with any os and any partition you might use.

Comment: Are these settings that are wholly in my motherboard settings (BIOS or similar), or is there some higher-level software I'd need to configure?

Comment: No you need not oconfigure anything else except your motherboard in which you first change the sata mode to raid, enable the control-i interface and then set the ssd to cache